# Haskell foldr with multiplication

Tags: haskell, fold

I'm supposed to write a function that will contain the product of each previous multiplication with that number

Basically this:

```
> productFromLeftToRight [2,3,4,5]
[120,60,20,5]
```

I'm supposed to use High Order functions, so folds and such. I'm thinking of using a foldr to traverse through the list with a lambda expression. This is what I'm thinking:

```
> productFromLeftToRight nums = foldr (\x acc -> [x] * acc ++ acc) [] nums
```

Since it would unravel like `f(2 (f 3 (f 4 (f 5 []))))` I would think I'm right, but I get the whole print error and I don't know how to multiply a number with the first element of acc ( head acc doesn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
productFromLeftToRight nums =
    init $ foldr (\x lst -> x * head lst : lst) [1] nums
```

The idea is to use a dummy element `1` to the answer list and remove it in the end.

Answer (score 4):

```
productFromLeftToRight = scanr1 (*)
```

or

```
productFromLeftToRight' = 
  snd . foldr (\x (acc,lst) -> (x * acc, x * acc : lst)) (1,[])
```

Comment: Works perfect but how could I translate that to a fold/map? We haven't gone over scanr1 in class sadly (shame because this is like 7 characters long)

Comment: I've added a second definition which uses `foldr`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one that doesn't do any post-processing after the `foldr`:

```
productFromLeftToRight = foldr (\n ps -> n * foldr const 1 ps : ps) []
```

Here, the inner `foldr const 1` is acting as a non-partial `head` function to get the first element of `ps`:

```
foldr const 1 (x:xs) = const x (foldr const 1 xs) = x
foldr const 1 []     = 1
```